# How can I add a print method for Audited gem in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, acts-as-audited

I'm using the gem `Audited` in my Rails app.  I want to create a way to print out the Audit record so I can have a feed of what has been changed by a User, or what has changed on an object.  Currently, I have setup a method called `print_audit` on each object that I'm using with `Audited`.  But this seems incredibly wrong.  I would like to override the `to_s` method on the Audit model... but I'm unsure what the correct way of doing that would be... is the approach incorrect and if not how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the following method as I find it much cleaner.

**Added file:** `config/initializers/audited_additional_methods.rb`

```
module Audited
  module Adapters
    module ActiveRecord
      class Audit < ::ActiveRecord::Base
        def to_s
          "Added my new to_s logic here"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is now a more straighforward method to accomplish this, as defined [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited#custom-audit-model) in the official documentation. Here is a snippet that would add to_s to each Audit instance:

```ruby
# config/initializers/audited.rb
class CustomAudit < Audited::Audit
  def to_s
    "This overrides the default to_s method!"
  end
end

Audited.config do |config|
  config.audit_class = CustomAudit
end
```